# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net

Tags: software-installation, ppa

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I always get this output:

```
...

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/q-quark/equalx/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

This `PPA` does not exist; that's why it is returning `404`

1. Check this `PPA` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and delete entry similar:

   ```
   deb  http://ppa.launchpad.net/q-quark/equalx/ubuntu xenial main
   ```
2. After that run command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`404` is Internet slang for "Object not found". Some research at [the source site](https://launchpad.net/~q-quark/+archive/ubuntu/equalx) shows that `equalx` is provided for the `Saucy (13.10)` and `Trusty (14.04)` releases. You're asking for `xenial`.

Either wait until the developer updates the PPA, or download the source and build it for Xenial yourself (this is hard).